# In vim, can I disable highlighting of text contained in <i> tags?

Tags: html, vim

Whenever I type something in italics in vim, it highlights it with a different background. In my case, I've got a white terminal background, and it chooses a horrible black background color for the italicized bits. It's awful.

Does anyone know how to disable this behavior? I presume it's sort of how `href` fields get underlined?

Comment: Try using [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) to figure out what highlight group is enabled and either edit the color or remove it or figure out how to stop if from highlighting the italics tabs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:highlight htmlItalic` will tell you the default highlighting:

```
htmlItalic     xxx term=italic cterm=italic gui=italic
```

The foreground and background are implicitly flipped by the `italic` style. To reset this, add the following to `~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim`:

```
highlight htmlItalic term=NONE cterm=NONE gui=NONE
```

Alternatively, to entirely disable HTML-specific highlighting, add this to `~/.vimrc`:

```
let html_no_rendering = 1
```